# chart.js responsive bar chart label sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

So I have a bar chart using chart.js and I have the responsive enabled. It seems to work well with some charts and not so well with others. For example my bar chart labels seem to not re-size with the window, but everything else does making the entire chart look awfully strange at smaller window sizes. How can I re-size the labels so that it scales all together? Any ideas? Thanks!

My fiddle:http://fiddle.jshell.net/SteveSerrano/e3o9z2wg/

Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="940" height="540"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: ["Adjust claims fairly", "Pays promptly", "Resolves issues quickly", "Communicates clearly, honestly to agents", "Underwriter knowledge/expirience", "Listens, responds to agents", "Consistant underwriting", "Easy, intuitive functionality-technology", "Stable underwriting market", "Flexible underwriting when warrented"],
    datasets: [
        {
        label: "My First dataset",
        //new option, barline will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
        type: "line",
        fillColor: "rgba(225,225,225,0.01)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#000000",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        data: [9.5, 9.4, 9.3, 9.2, 9.2, 9.1, 9, 9, 9, 9]
    }, {
        label: "My First dataset",
        //new option, barline will default to bar as that what is used to create the scale
        type: "bar",
        fillColor: "rgba(225,50,50,0.8)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(225,50,50,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,20,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [7.4, 7.6, 6.2, 6.3, 6.8, 5.8, 7.1, 6.1, 7.6, 5.2]
    }]
};
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
//canvases
var lineBar = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

//charts
var myLineBarChart = new Chart(lineBar).Overlay(barChartData);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem has more to do with the really long x axis labels than the responsiveness. That said, setting `maintainAspectRatio` will solve your problem.

```
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;
```

Note that you can do this per chart too.

---

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio too, you can extend the chart to trim the labels like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31699438/360067

Comment: Hey thanks! But when I switch it to false it sends my canvas height skyrocketing to 4320! Does not do this in the fiddle, but it does on the page I'm working on. Any ideas why?

Comment: the `responsive` option will size the graph to fit its parent container. Try setting a max-height on the parent.