# (Ionic 3) How to make font size of labels in charts.js responsive?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, chart.js, responsive, font-size

```
this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {

          labels: ["", "", "", "", ""],
            datasets: [{
                label: '',
                data: [12, 19, 7, 15,10]
            }]
        },    

  options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                display:false
                    },
                categoryPercentage: 1.0,
                barPercentage: 0.4,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    fontSize: 10,
                    font: 'Georgia',
                    labelString: 'service request',
                    fontColor: '#808080',
                    padding: 0
                        }

                }],
```

This is my typescript code snippet. Font size is 10, which is fine if the phone screen is small, but if I view it on a tablet or a larger screen size, it becomes blurry.  I don't know how to make texts in the labels of bar charts responisve.

HTML code:

```
        <ion-content>
    <div class="container" style="width:100%; height:25%;">
    <div id="bar" style="position: relative; width:50%; height:100%;">
    <ion-card>
     <ion-card-content >
    <canvas id="bars" #barCanvas></canvas>
    </ion-card-content>
   </ion-card>
  </div>
   </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Look at that post https://stackoverflow.com/q/33133028/6018581 think it will help

Comment: I tried the solutions mentioned in that post. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way possible is to use [Scriptable options](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/options#scriptable-options) according to this [jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/simonbrunel/L8qhvppd/)

```
 font: function(context) {
  var width = context.chart.width;
  var size = Math.round(width / 32);
    return {
      size: size,
      weight: 600
    };
}
```

Comment: If this one was helpfull to you please click on the top arow on the left of my post (also the green cross for Mon)

Comment: Hi, I'm not able to make this work for scaleLabel. I guess that solution only works for dataLabels. I want to resize my xaxis and yaxis label according to window size.

Comment: Like, in the code above : I want to resize the xAxis labelString : "service request" according to screen width.

Comment: I did it with jQuery in my last project something like that post https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to that for charts.js labels? How do I access the labelString component?